# No autocomplete for two way data binding in Angular?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, webstorm

In WebStorm/IntelliJ when I attempt to use two way data binding (e.g. `[(ngModel)]`) there is no autocomplete that pops up. Also when `ctrl` hovering over `[(ngModel)]` there is no link to jump to anything. It's like the IDE is completely unaware of this feature. My only guess is that maybe because I'm using the latest version of Angular that maybe the IDE hasn't caught up to it yet? I am using the latest versions of each IDE.

Comment: Maybe this will help - https://angular.io/guide/language-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WEB-28107](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28107) is fixed in upcoming Webstorm 2018.3

Comment: Awesome! Getting a direct response from a dev is always a warm fuzzy feeling :)